# Vue/Laravel How to load axios calls faster

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using an Axios call which is calling a large json file. Everytime this call is made the page hangs for around 2 seconds before loading the content, is there a way to either not make the page freeze so I can show a loading bar or just speed up the axios call altogether? I am trying to save the json data in a global variable however I cant figure out how to do that

Comment: Is it the call, or the rendering? Axios calls are asynchronous by default, so they shouldn't lock up the page, but if it's a huge JSON file your JavaScript front-end has to render, that might be locking up the browser there.

Comment: Ah yeah, the call is instantaneous, but the rendering locks up the page. Is there any techniques or methods with vue to either speed it up or render without locking up the page so I could use a vuetify loader to indicate the data is loading

Comment: It's gonna depend a lot on the data and what you're doing with it. Potential approaches at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515997/how-to-handle-vue-2-memory-usage-for-large-data-50-000-objects for working with big datasets; are you sure you can't paginate or something?

Comment: So what i'm doing with the data currently is loading it all and using a v-if statement to see if the data belongs on the page. So is the approach I am taking appropriate or should I use something like Vuex or the laravel controllers to handle this logic

Comment: You'll be much better off doing pagination at the Laravel controller level, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I see no other reason for the page to freeze unless the data in your .json file is too long.
In that case, I strongly recommend that you store them in the database and use the laravel pagination.
If the data is very large but does not follow a pattern, you can put it in the controller and separate it by if according to your needs.